# Azure External tables no longer working. after working

Tags: azure, external-tables

I created some Azure Extended tables that queried SqlServer. They seemed to be working fine. Then about 8 hours later stopped working giving me the error.
"An error occurred while establishing connection to remote data source:
Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider:
Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17"

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password1!';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SQLServerCredentials
WITH IDENTITY = 'adminadmin', SECRET = 'password1!';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [dbI]
WITH
( TYPE = RDBMS ,
LOCATION = 'sql-1' ,
DATABASE_NAME = 'dbI' ,
CREDENTIAL = SQLServerCredentials
)
```

I can't get CONNECTION_OPTIONS to work in the create data source command either.
CONNECTION_OPTIONS = 'ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly',

I can connect to the external tables and script them out. The external tables are in the Tables/External Tables on Azure.

To  be able to select top 1000 rows from external table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created Master Key and Scoped credential with server credentials and created Data source using below code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [dbs]
WITH
( TYPE = RDBMS ,
  LOCATION = 'dbserevere' ,
  DATABASE_NAME = 'db' ,
  CREDENTIAL = SQLServerCredentials
)
```

Created External table with created data source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbstudents2(
  Id INT,
  Name VARCHAR(20)
)
WITH (
    DATA_SOURCE = dbs,
    SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo',
    OBJECT_NAME = 'students'
)
```

Selected data using `select * from dbstudents2` I got same error

[image]

The issue might be causing because of wrong location here I provided Azure sql server name. I created data source using code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [db]
WITH
( TYPE = RDBMS ,
  LOCATION = 'dbserevere.database.windows.net' ,
  DATABASE_NAME = 'db' ,
  CREDENTIAL = SQLServerCredentials1
)
```

[image]

Created external table with above data source selected the data.
I am able to retrieve the data:

[image]

Comment: I tried it but it's telling me login failed for user. But the table design info did make it to Azure. When you scoped credential the IDENTITY is a valid SQLServer login and the SECRET is his password? And the password has to be masterkeyed?

Comment: Create Scoped credential with CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<Password>';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL <name> WITH IDENTITY = '<Sql ServeruserName>',
SECRET = '<sql serverPassword>';